# Is there an equivalent to emacsclient for vim?

Tags: vim, emacs

With emacs, you can use the `emacsclient` program to open a file in an already existing emacs frame.  Is there any way to do this with vim?  In other words, I want to have something I can type at the command prompt to open a file in a vim window I already have open rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Not your exact question, but emacs has some [VIM emulation modes](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2218), at least one of which is trying to be very faithful to VIM itself.  If a mostly-vim-like mode in emacs is acceptable for some of your uses, emacsclient's functionality comes along with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually figured this one out on my own.  This is supported in vim natively if you use the --remote option.  Ex:

```
gvim --remote foo.txt
```

You can also specify a server name:

```
gvim --remote foo.txt --servername foo
```

I added the following function to my .zshrc (but it should work in bash as well) to make this a bit easier:

```
function vs() {
    gvim --remote-silent $@
}
```

This way, all you have to type in is `vs <filename>`.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there an equivalent to emacsclient for vim?

Not really.

> I want to have something I can type at the command prompt to open a file in a vim window I already have open rather than creating a new one

This can be done with `gvim --remote`.

But emacs client is much more useful than just `gvim --remote`. With emacs client you can open a duplicate emacs gtk window. Then you can have emacs open with some files on your machine, ssh in with X11 forwarding and run emacsclient to pop up a emacs window on your remote machine. It's like screen for emacs. Unfortunately, `gvim --remote` only works to evaluate expressions, send keybindings, and open files, which while useful and matching your usecase, is not the same as emacsclient.

Comment: More like a comment, not an answer to op.